# Query Firebase Database With Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query an entry in my firebase realtime database with Swift to basically see if an entry exists with the `owner` = 33206. My current code is not returning what I need, how can I fix this query?

Here is my code:

```
var promoCodes: DatabaseReference {
    return ref.child("PromoCodes")
}


func getIsAffiliate() {
    promoCodes.child("owner").queryEqual(toValue: 33206).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        print("SNAP HERE: \(snapshot)")
        AffiliateService.isAffiliate = snapshot == nil
    }
}
```

Output: `SNAP HERE: Snap (owner) <null>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot` passed to your code will never be `nil`. To check if there are matching nodes, you can check [`snapshot.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#exists) instead.